# Auto forward user at login to specific url

Tags: user

When a user calls http://moss.domain.tld he should be auto forwarded to a url  like http://moss.domain.tld/customers/xyz based upon his user or assigned group. Is this possible with sharepoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to develop or use a custom solution to accomplish this, e.g. a component that inspects the logged-in user and does the forward.

If you want to build one yourself:
http://blog.furuknap.net/redirecting-users-based-on-group-membership

An example of a third-party webpart:
http://store.bamboosolutions.com/pfi-14-group-redirect-web-part.aspx